# HikariCP added to the Spring project gives error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, hikaricp

I added a new data source config in the project using the HikariCP provided:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public DataSource customDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {

        final CustomHikariDataSource dataSource = (CustomHikariDataSource) properties
            .initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(CustomHikariDataSource.class).build();
        if (properties.getName() != null) {
            dataSource.setPoolName(properties.getName());
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(
        value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE,
        proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() throws SQLException {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    private static class CustomHikariDataSource extends HikariDataSource {
        @Override
        public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

            Connection connection = super.getConnection();
//            connection.setSchema(Utilities.getTenantId());
            return connection;
        }
    }
}
```

I started to get these immediately afterwards:

```
herefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-11-24 12:21:42.831 ERROR 26227 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customDataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2020-11-24 12:21:42.844  INFO 26227 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-11-24 12:21:42.850  WARN 26227 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2020-11-24 12:21:42.863  INFO 26227 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-11-24 12:21:42.876 ERROR 26227 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.monytyz.billing.BillingApplication.main(BillingApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:an]
```

The project runs fine before this. What's the issue for these errors and how to solve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `Datasource` Bean and also autowire it in same configuration class

Move `Datasource` Bean to a different configuration class